# How to resolve android.view.InflateException on Binary XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-10.0

In my scenario, While I am trying to run my android application I am getting `android.view.InflateException` on `Binary XML` file line #120 in fragment section. I can't get more information about this error but while I am changing android `API 28 to 29` only I am getting this error. how to resolve this?

**MyCode Below**

```
<include 
  layout="@layout/fragmentsection"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:gravity="center" />
```

**MyError Logs**

```
Process: com.orgin.project_532, PID: 9982
Android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #120 in com.orgin.project_532: layout/fragmentsection: Binary XML file line #58 in com.orgin.project_532: layout/fragmentsecondsection: Error inflating exception.
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58 in com.orgin.project_532: layout/fragmnetsecondsection: Error inflating class com.orgin.orgSeekBar
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: That exception pretty much always has a child exception that's the real cause.  Post the full log.

Comment: That's not the full stack trace.  Its MUCH larger.  I can tell you the problem is in a Seekbar in the fragmentsection.xml file.